# Tkinter how to fix non symmetrical button

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-button

As you can see in the picture, everything is aligned properly, but the equation button is not symmetrical in size from both sides. For example if I change the equation character to a number, then everything is perfect. I tried to search if I could add padding to only one side of the button(not grid), but couldn't find a solution for it. Any ideas how to fix it?

[Photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B6rJd.png)

Here's the current code of the button:

```
button_equation = Button(window, text="=", bg=button_bg, fg=button_fg, activeforeground=button_afg,
                     activebackground=button_abg, highlightbackground=button_afg, borderwidth=button_border,
                     padx=26, pady=0, font=(font, 16))
```

Comment: You can add padding to one side of a widget by putting it inside a tuple: `padx=(left,right)` or `pady=(up,down)`. Also, show us the code used for that button.

Comment: That cause an error in a widget, for example if I write padx=(1, 1), the error is "_tkinter.TclError: bad screen distance "1 1". Tuple works in a grid config, but I can't get it to work in a widget config.

Comment: You should use it with grid, not as widget option. `button_equation.grid(....,padx=(..,..))`/

Comment: If you used `grid()` on those buttons, add `sticky="ew"`.